# Does Greenplum database support parameterized cursor?

Tags: greenplum, database-cursor

Does Greenplum support parameterized cursors like Oracle?

Comment: It is very, very rare to use a cursor in Greenplum.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Greenplum doesn't support parameterized cursors from the documentation present in pivotal site 
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43310/ref_guide/sql_commands/DECLARE.html

From the documentation, I cannot see any parameterized declaration definition

```
DECLARE name [BINARY] [INSENSITIVE] [NO SCROLL] CURSOR 
     [{WITH | WITHOUT} HOLD] 
     FOR query [FOR READ ONLY]
```

oracle's documentation  is clear 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems013.htm

**parameter_name**
A variable declared as the formal parameter of a cursor. A cursor parameter can appear in a query wherever a constant can appear. The formal parameters of a cursor must be IN parameters. The query can also reference other PL/SQL variables within its scope.